# Need more elegant solution to even string length

Tags: python, string, string-length

*Here's the task I got:*

Given a string of even length, return the first half. So the string "WooHoo" yields "Woo".

```
first_half('WooHoo') → 'Woo'
first_half('HelloThere') → 'Hello'
first_half('abcdef') → 'abc'
```

*Here's my solution:*

```
def first_half(str):
    if len(str) % 2 == 0:
        b = len(str) // 2
        return str[:b]
```

*My question is:*

Can you show me a simpler solution in Python of course that doesn't require me to use a variable for half of the string length (b)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python:

```
str = "WooHoo"   
str = str[:-len(str)/2]
```

Answer (score 3):

In python:

```
return str[0: int(len( str )/2)];
```

here no need to check whether it's even or odd lenght. `len( str )/2` will round itself.

---

Answered following before question re-edit:

In Javascript:

```
 var str = "WooHoo";
 if (str.length%2 == 0) {
     console.log(str.substr(0, str.length / 2));
    }
```

Answer is `Woo`.

Or just use:

```
str.substr(0, str.length / 2);
```

No need to check `if (str.length%2 == 0)`.

Other languages have the `length` property, and `substring` function too.

Comment: your Python code results in a TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: figured it out, my interpreter is 3.3 and your code was 2.x so integer division symbol was the problem (// 3.3.)  vs (/ 2.x)

Comment: @noob81 sorry, i forgot casting to int()

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the most simple and straight-forward solution.**

Running until the middle of the string, here, `//` is used to confirm that I am getting only int values after dividing, in case the length is odd.

```
 def first_half(str):

     return str[:(len(str)//2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
def first_half(str):
    if len(str) % 2 == 0:
        return str[:len(str) // 2]
```

or maybe like this?

```
def first_half(str):
    return str[:len(str) // 2 if len(str) % 2 == 0 else 0]
```

This is quite vague as you haven't explained what to do when an uneven length string is provided.

Comment: as the task says, the uneven is irrelevant right now, but yes your solution is a lot closer to what I imagined than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_half(str):
  calc = len(str) / 2
  if calc:
    return str[:calc]
    
  else:
    if len(str) <= 0:
      return str
    
first_half('abcdef')
```

Comment: Please markdown your code and provide description for further detail.